# How can I get a specific large file off of a broken SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have had a Patriot Torqz 128gb SSD for a little over a year. It never gave me any trouble until last week, when I returned to the office after about 30 minutes to find Windows hung. After multiple different attempts and strategies, I was never able to recover.

I pulled the drive and put it in a USB external enclosure. I can now access it and recover almost all of my files. The most important file, however, is a 3.2GB backup of all my e-mails over the past couple years, and every time I try to copy this file off the SSD, it hangs at the same location (about 940MB into the copy).

The most important thing to me is this particular file. I would gladly consider the drive a loss if I could get this file back intact. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I have had this too for over a year. I've managed to avoid the spot, but once I hit it, my system freezes (that's on Linux and Windows, BTW). I'd consider the file lost. Better save the rest while it still works

Comment: @Mark: It is a PST

Answer (score 1):

Use Unstoppable Copier http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29 to recover the file and then the Inbox Repair tool (scanpst.exe) to repair the PST.